# I want to implement a image croper for web using flutter

Tags: flutter, image, web, crop

Here I have a blocker in development. I want to create a UI by which I can change my profile picture after croping image, and this is a web application So how can I achieve this task like crop image and chang dp for web using flutter.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it yet, but this looks very promising:

https://pub.dev/packages/extended_image

Comment: Hello christian, I tried it but failed to show cropped image in UI.